# Developing a web-app on Windows and Linux

Tags: python, git, cross-platform, virtualenv

I'm developing a web-app and the work needs to be done from two computers, one is running Linux the other is running Windows.

This app is developed with Pyramid framework on Python 2.6.7 (this is what the server runs, and I can't change it)

Following the tutorials in Pyramid site, I've created a `virtualenv` on the Linux machine, and created a project - tested it and it seems to run without issues on the Linux machine. Now in order to sync the work to Windows, I thought of using git (with a free private projcet from bitbucket). I created a git project and pushed it to bitbucket. I used this [.gitignore](https://raw.github.com/github/gitignore/master/Python.gitignore) file template and I've also added this line (I believe that venv is OS specific, but I could be wrong):

```
venv
```

After I cloned the project to Windows, I don't have a virtualenv - How do I create a venv that would be compatible with the one that exists on the Linux machine (my Windows machine has Python 2.7 installed on it, no sqlalchemy, etc.)? What is the 'correct' way of doing it? Should I just give app (it was a spelling mistake, *but* I'll leave it for now) Windows and use Ubuntu on a virtualbox?

**EDIT:**

Although I have already accepted Rostyslav Dzinko's answer regarding the use of a `requirements.txt` file, the right way is to actually use the built in `setup.py` that is generated by pyramid's scaffold mechanism during the `pcreate` process. So if anyone encounter this issue please consider trying:

```
python setup.py develop
```

Comment: Which Python version (and distribution, eg. ActiveState) do you have installed in Windows?

Comment: @VasileiosLourdas I have an official CPython 2.7.2 on Windows, but on this machine I can install whatever I want/need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualenv creates virtual environment for your Python interpreter. It means that each virtual environment can have different versions of same packages installed or different packages at all that are important only for your project (dependencies).

If you want to manage dependencies, you can use [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) to make your new virtual environment synchronized with old one.

All you need to do is to create [requirements.txt](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) file and fill it with dependencies, e.g:

```
pyramid==1.0.1
...
```

Let this file be in your git repository.

After cloning the source into newly created virtualenv on a new machine, you can install all dependencies with pip:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: should I run `venv/bin/pip freeze > requirements.txt` on the Linux machine?

Comment: It's up to you. pip freeze is used to support installing different versions of your project elsewhere (that have different dependencies). If you plan that - you should do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! another quick one - Do I need to install on Windows the same versions of python and virtualenv which are installed on Linux prior to creating the virtualenv on Windows and using pip?

Comment: It's highly recommended and surely won't rise incompatibility issues

Answer (score 0):

A virtual-env is a Python runtime environment installed on your system. It isn't part of your code-base and so shouldn't be in your Git repository.

Install a virtual-env separately on each machine you use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I already stated in the question, I added the venv directory to the `.gitignore` file. My question was how to sync between two virtualenv's in two different OS's